# É possível criar com CSS um elemento tipo um Selo de Carta?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Qual a melhor forma ou forma mais indicada para construir um elemento similar a um Selo de Carta apenas com CSS? *(no momento não queria ter que usar SVG)*

Eu estou tentando construir essa forma com HTML/CSS e a opção que tenho no momento não me agrada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A opção que encontrei é essa abaixo. Porém não me agrada, pois eu iria precisar de MUITAS `div`s para terminar a forma, além disso se eu quiser mudar o tamanho do Selo ficaria meio complicado e pouco aplicável.

```css
.selo {
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.topo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.bola {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="selo">
  <div class="topo">
    <div class="bola"></div>
    <div class="bola"></div>
    <div class="bola"></div>
    <div class="bola"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Com CSS e HTML como construir esse elemento de forma prática e com menos código?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044525/how-can-i-create-a-postage-stamp-border

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A propriedade `border-image` é ótima para isso.

Ela permite usar uma técnica chamada 9 patch, que recorta a imagem em quadrantes.

```
border-image: url(   ) 20 20 20 20 round round;

/*         imagem -^   ^---- medidas ----^ ^-metodo-^      */
```

### Demonstrando:

Nossa imagem de referência:

[image: 9 Patch]

Clique em executar para ver aplicada:

```css
.selo {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    /* O que nos interessa é o border apenas, nas linhas abaixo. acima é só pro demo */
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5VX5.png) 20 20 20 20 round round;
}
```

```html
<div class="selo">
   Chegou carta!<br>
   C O R R E I O S
</div>

<div class="selo">
   ... e outra carta, um bocado maior.<br>
   <br>
   Quem sabe é um cheque bem gordo.
</div>
```

Documentação:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Compatibilidade:

> https://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

### Visualizando o que aconteceu:

Para entender melhor o efeito, segue uma versão colorida da imagem:

[image: 9 patch]

Para facilitar o cálculo, em ambos os casos usamoss uma imagem de 60px de largura, para que cada quadrante ficasse com 20px:

[image: Quadrantes]

No **border-image** especificaremos esses `20px` como distância para o topo, a lateral direita, parte de baixo e lateral esquerda. O resto será "acomodado" para preencher o desenho.

As três formas de preenchimento são:

- `stretch` - ela "estica" os pedaços intermediários até preencher o espaço;
- `repeat` - em vez de "esticar", os pedaços intermediários são usados como textura repetitiva;
- `round` - tenta fazer uma textura repetitiva, mas dá uma "ajeitada" arredondando as medidas para que não apareçam emendas.

Note que no nosso caso, eu usei 20 em todos os quadrantes só pra facilitar. Nada impede da imagem ter proporções diferentes em cada lado.

```css
.selo {
    margin:10px; 
    padding:10px; 
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvUY1.png) 20 20 20 20 round round;
}
```

```html
<div class="selo">
   Chegou carta!<br>
   
   C O R R E I O S
</div>
```

Comment: Não conhecia isso, muito bom

Comment: Bacco realmente uma excelente explicação, nunca tinha entendido direito como funcionava o border-imagem valeu mesmo!

Comment: Cada solução bacana que nem imaginamos. Muito bom @Bacco!

Answer (score 4):

<sub><sup>**Não sou de fazer duplo post, mas tem muita informação no outro - note que postei como community wiki pra não abusar da pontuação**
**Para quem não sabe, postagens marcadas como Wiki da Comunidade, mesmo que bem votadas, não dão pontos para o autor.**</sup></sub>

## Usando bordas

Só pra completar o post, segue uma versão com bordas e pseudoelementos:

Basicamente é uma borda branca com pontos, sobre uma borda sólida preta:

```css
.selo {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  border:10px dotted #fff;
}

.selo:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute; box-sizing: border-box;
  top:-5px; right:-5px; bottom: -5px; left:-5px; 
  border:10px solid #000;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="selo">
  Carta 1<br>
  00000-000 - São Paulo - SP
</div>

<div class="selo">
  Cartinha 2
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom mestre! Valeu por contribuir!

Answer (score 2):

## opção 1

Usando `outline` e `outline-offset` o outline funciona como uma bordar e o offset coloca essa borar um pouco para dentro, simulando o efeito, o tamanho da borda se controla pelo `outline-width` e o `outline-color` a cor. Além disso fica bem responsivo e não perde resolução.

Suporte dos browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=outline

Documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset

```css
div {
 width: 30%;
 height: 40%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
 outline-style: dotted;
    outline-width: 2em;
    outline-color: #fff;
    outline-offset: -1em;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px;
}


div > section {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 40px;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga labore illo rem ut. Iusto, temporibus laboriosam? Odio sapiente veritatis similique.
 </section>
</div>

<div style="outline-color: #f00; width: 300px; height: 200px">
 <section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga labore illo rem ut. Iusto, temporibus laboriosam? Odio sapiente veritatis similique.
 </section>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Não funciona no IE :(

---

## Opção 2

Além da opção citada pelo @bacco outra opção seria usando radial-gradiente, assim não é preciso usar uma imagem como referência para as bordas.

***O pontos positivos***, não tem imagem envolvida, não tem requisição de img no server, não tem problema de resolução caso queira mudar o tamanho e é fácil de trocar a cor a hora que eu quiser.

***Pontos negativos***, não é tão flexível quanto o `border-image` no quesito *largura x altura*, e não é tão prático quanto a manutenção do código.

Segue o exemplo. Repare que é apenas uma div que é o selo. ela usa dois pseudo elementos. um com o *pattern* das bolinhas, e outro para fazer o box do conteúdo.

```css
div {
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 /* border: 1px solid; */
 background-color: black;
}
div::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 /* background-color: aquamarine; */
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 0%, #fff 49%, transparent 51%, transparent 100%);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-position: -25px -25px;
}
div::after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: calc(300px - 50px);
    height: calc(400px - 50px);
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

div > section {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 40px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga labore illo rem ut. Iusto, temporibus laboriosam? Odio sapiente veritatis similique.
  </section>
</div>
```

Suporte dos browser a partir do IE10: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Documentação do radial-gradiente da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient