# Como ajustar Background para se ajustar dentro de container sem cortar nada?

Tags: css, css3, background, background-image

Tenho uma *pattern* que se repete tanto em X quanto em Y que quero usar como `background` em uma `div`, mas gostaria que ele coube-se dentro da `div` sem cortar nas laterais como está na imagem. *(quero que tenham apenas estrelas inteiras no background)*. Queria que o `background` se ajusta-se de forma a não cortar pedaços das estrela, ficando composto apenas por figuras inteiras.

O intenção é que o `background` se repita e encaixe dentro do *container*, mas sem cortar as extremidades, veja as sinalizações em vermelho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Existe alguma forma de controlar como o background se repete dentro do *container* para evitar que algum pedaço fique cortado?** 
*(o camanho do container não é fixo, pode variar altura e largura)*

```css
.x {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: red;
    background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Toolbar_Icon_Set_by_shlyapnikova/32/star.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

Imagem: https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Toolbar_Icon_Set_by_shlyapnikova/32/star.png

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer sua class "x" ser apenas 1 estrela que é a sua imagem e não iria cortar. E repetir a sua class "x" ? Usa o "background-repeat: no-repeat;" para não repetir a imagem de background. É apenas um sugestão.

Comment: @RicardoLucas mas mesmo dessa forma ela poderia ficar cortada no final a direita... E eu ainda teria que ter várias divs uma abaixo da outro para conseguir ocupar o container inteiro com estrelas....

Comment: Não não cara quando você colocar o no-repeat no background ele apenas deixa 1 imagens que é da sua estrela, dai se vc fizer varias vezes a chamada da classe "x" vai aparecer a estrela normal sem estar cortada vc quer que eu faca ? pra vc visualizar ?

Comment: Mas ai vc teria que ter uma div para cada estrala? Eu editei a imagem da pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Opção `round` da propriedade `background-repeat`:

A opção `round` faz uma mínima distorção na imagem de fundo para que ela se encaixe da melhor forma possível para não cortar a imagem.

```css
div {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrv4v.png);
    background-repeat:round;

    /* daqui pra baixo é só para facilitar a demonstração */
    resize:both; overflow:auto; width:60%; padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Varie o tamanho da<br>
div arrastando pelo cantinho para testar!
</div>
```

É uma propriedade bem suportada:

> https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-repeat-round-space

**Originalmente, eu tinha ido por este caminho:**

[É possível criar com CSS um elemento tipo um Selo de Carta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/326205/70)

Veja aplicado numa `div`:

```css
div {
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrv4v.png) 1 1 1 1 fill round;

    /* daqui pra baixo é só para facilitar a demonstração */
    resize:both; overflow:auto; width:60%; padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Varie o tamanho da<br>
div para testar!
</div>
```

Depois de uma conversa com o autor da pergunta no chat, chegamos na solução do topo, que é a mais adequada. Esta segunda é adequada em casos que envolvam textura tanto na borda quanto no fundo.