# Como fazer um fundo de bolinhas com CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu estava querendo fazer um fundo pontilhado, tipo um monte de bolinhas para fazer o `background` de um site,

Exemplo do que estou querendo fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**É possível chegar nesse resultado apenas com CSS sem precisar de uma imagem?**

Eu tentei com `repeating-radial-gradient,` mas não deu muito certo...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, red 0%, red 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);

}
```

Comment: Uma possível solução: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29854378/8133067

Comment: É por ai mesmo! Facilitou a vida de quem vai responder... Tenta bolar uma resposta para trazer esse conteúdo tb pro pt.STOF ;)

Comment: Ah, entendi, era essa a intenção da pergunta? Agora infelizmente não vou conseguir, só fiz uma pesquisa rápida e postei o link. Tentarei à noite, mas, até lá alguém já deve ter respondido. Mas de qualquer forma teria que estudar o assunto, porque não domino muito essa área! :)

Comment: @PedroGaspar tranquilo jovem, valeu sua intenção. Mas as vezes eu faço perguntas apenas para manter a comunidade movimentada e trazer outros conteúdos aqui pro nosso site tb. Tmj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como são dois padrões, você pode utilizar múltiplas "imagens" de *background*, onde as imagens são geradas pelo próprio CSS.

Para desenhar o círculo:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle, yellow 0%, yellow 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%)
```

Bastando mudar a cor para as outras cores.

Veja um exemplo:

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, gold 0%, gold 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%),
                    radial-gradient(circle, red 0%, red 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: 0 0, 20px 20px;
}
```

#### Deixando o padrão mais dinâmico

Caso queira deixar um pouco mais dinâmico, você pode colocar a dimensão base em uma variável do CSS e utilizar `calc` para calcular as posições. Por exemplo:

```css
body {
  --size: 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, gold 0%, gold 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%),
                    radial-gradient(circle, red 0%, red 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: var(--size) var(--size);
  background-position: 0 0, calc(var(--size)/2) calc(var(--size)/2);
}
```

Outra pergunta interessante sobre definir padrões no *background* utilizando imagens que pode ser útil para quem ler essa resposta é:

- [Como ajustar Background para se ajustar dentro de container sem cortar nada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/333794/5878)